# Converting SAS Character of form "mo-yr" to a SAS date

Tags: date, character, sas

I'm trying to convert a SAS string of the form "MO-YR" (e.g. "Jan-04") to a SAS date.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a date format in SAS that takes that form, so I can't just use an input statement like this date = input(datestring, sasformat).

I've been using this site to find date formats: http://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

MONYY seems to work for me.

```
data _null_;
input @1 mydate monyy6.;
put mydate= date9.;
datalines;
Jan-04
Dec-12
;;;;
run;
```

Puts the correct values to the log.